# Why are utm parameters in playstore url being ignored and overwritten when installing the app over the web via. Play.google.com?

Tags: google-play, utm

While installing the app over the web via play.google.com along with utm parameters, the utm params are ignored by google play and are overriden as source to be google-play and medium organic. Why is url utm being ingored in this scenario? How to track the conversion in this case?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, so you probably won't get any answers.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the correction.